# typeRoots in TypeScript project. Could not find a declaration file for module

Tags: typescript, types, tsc

I have set the following properties in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"typeRoots": ["./build/types"],
"declaration": true,
"declarationDir": "./build/types",
```

And I have file `main.ts`.

After that, when I run `tsc`, I get this project structure:

- build -
  main.js

  - types (in build folder) - main.d.ts

Then I create a `some.ts` file and import the `foo` function from the `main.js` from `build/main.js`  and I get this error:

`TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './build/main.js'. absolute/path/build/main.js/ implicitly has an 'any' type.`

However, if I move the file `main.d.ts` from `types` folder to `build` folder, it will work fine.

How i can use the `types` folder for my declaration? IDK. Help

The message is this: if we were given the `declarationDir` property, then there will surely be a way to apply it, otherwise why do we need it?

main.ts:

`export default function bar(a: string): string { return 'Hello ' + a + ' !'; }`

build:

main.js:

`export default function bar(a) { return 'Hello ' + a + ' !'; }`

build/types:

main.d.ts

`export default function bar(a: string): string;`

I try change `typeRoot` and `types` property in my tsc, but it not working...